# C# close a shared outlook calendar

Tags: c#, calendar, outlook, interop

I wrote a tool to read appointments of shared folders. After that I have a lot of shared calendar folder inside my calendar view in outlook.

No I want to remove/close/disconnect the shared calender.

I used this solution to open the shared calender: [Connect to Outlook calendar from C# using Interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216064/connect-to-outlook-calendar-from-c-sharp-using-interop)

But how can I remove/close/disconnect it?

I tested the .Delete() operation, but I think this will delete the calendar from the sharing user and thats not my plan.

Hope somebody can help me!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the to use the [Remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869479(v=office.15).aspx) method of the NavigationFolder class for shared calendars, not Folder.Delete. Here is what MSDN states:

*Only removable folders, NavigationFolder objects with an IsRemovable property value set to True, can be removed from a NavigationFolders collection. This means that you can use NavigationFolders.Remove to remove shared folders, public folders, and linked folders.*

See [How to: Enumerate Active Folders in the Calendar View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff863591.aspx) for more information.